# The Frattini subgroup is a characteristic subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

I am revising for my Group Theory exam and am stuck on the following question;

The Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$ of a group $G$ is defined to be the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$. Prove that $\Phi(G)$ is a characteristic subgroup of G.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT.** If $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, and $f\colon G\to K$ is a homomorphism with kernel contained in $H$, then $f(H)$ is a maximal subgroup of $f(G)$.

Answer (score 3):

We need this Lemma 1:

> Automorphism maps a maximal subgroup to another maximal subgroup.

The proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3646314/435467).

Let $\alpha:G \rightarrow G \in Aut(G)$.

Let:

$\Phi(G) = \bigcap\limits_{M \: maximal \: in \: G} \: M$

be the Frattini subgroup of $G$.

By Lemma 1 $\alpha(M)$ is also another maximal subgroup of $G$. We could just quit here by noticing that $Aut(G)$ maps maximal subgroups of $G$ to another maximal subgroups so their intersection stays the same, which means Frattini subgroup is a characteristic subgroup of $G$. However I want to make it more clear by writing it more formal:

$\alpha(\Phi(G)) = \alpha\left(\bigcap\limits_{M \: maximal \: in \: G} \: M \right) = \bigcap\limits_{\alpha(M) \: maximal \: in \: G} \alpha(M) = \Phi(G)$.

Answer (score 2):

let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary automorphism of $G$. If $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$, then $\alpha(M)$ is a maximal subgroup, too. then $\alpha(\phi(G))=\alpha(\cap M)=\cap \alpha(M)=\cap M'=\phi(G)$, M' is a maximal subgroup.

Comment: How do you know $\alpha(M)$ is maximal?

Comment: @ponchan Automorphism maps maximal subgroup to another maximal subgroup, the proof is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3646314/435467.